# Passing multiple 3D arrays over ajax POST

Tags: ajax, json, post

I'm having trouble with data formatting. I have several 3-D arrays (arrays of arrays of arrays for the sticklers) that I want to pass to a PHP function through an ajax POST.  I've tried combining them into an object and then stringifying it with JSON.stringify:

```
var postFile = '/games/saveMap';
var postObj = {'mapTiles':mapArray,
            'tileRots':rotations,
            'ceilings':ceiling,
            'floors':floor,
            'pitDepth':depth,
            'sections':sectionNames,
            'mapName':$('#mapName').val()
    }
var postData = JSON.stringify(postObj);
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: postFile,
        data: postObj,
        success: function(data)
        {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
        }
});
```

Regardless of whether I send postObj or postData I get an error that the index is undefined for all of the indexes in the object. What is wrong with my format? What format does the POST need to detect my indexes?

EDIT: While I don't see a problem in the server side syntax, it is what is throwing the "undefined index" error:

```
$mapName=$_POST['mapName'];
$sectionNames=$_POST['sections'];
$mapArrays=$_POST['mapTiles'];
$rotations=$_POST['tileRots'];
$ceilings=$_POST['ceilings'];
$floors=$_POST['floors'];
$pitDepth=$_POST['pitDepth'];
```

Comment: Using the code var postData = "mapName="+$('#mapName').val()+"&sections="+JSON.stringify(sectionNames)+"&mapTiles="+JSON.stringify(mapArray)+"&tileRots="+JSON.stringify(rotations)+"&ceilings="+JSON.stringify(ceiling)+"&floors="+JSON.stringify(floor)+"&pitDepth="+JSON.stringify(depth); to generate the string, I am able to see the data with a print_r($_POST) with the exception of the map name, but the indices are still gone undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was referencing the object on the PHP side. The correct syntax turned out to be

```
$mapName=$_POST->mapName;
$sectionNames=$_POST->sections;
$mapArrays=$_POST->mapTiles;
$rotations=$_POST->tileRots;
$ceilings=$_POST->ceilings;
$floors=$_POST->floors;
$pitDepth=$_POST->pitDepth;
```

Something I should have remembered from my Java/C++ days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/games/saveMap',
    data: {
        'mapTiles':mapArray,
        'tileRots':rotations,
        'ceilings':ceiling,
        'floors':floor,
        'pitDepth':depth,
        'sections':sectionNames,
        'mapName':$('#mapName').val()
    },
    success: function(data)
    {
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Undefined Index" for each of the indexes on the PHP side. Did you change anything besides copying the url and data variables in directly?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought your undefined index was on the JavaScript side. On the PHP side what happens when you print_r($_POST)? Do you see that post data?

Comment: Thanks for the debug tool. The data it prints look like the kinds of numbers I expect in mapArray, but there are only enough of them (2000) to account for 1/10th of the array, since every other number seems to be an index in brackets. I see no indexes strings, but the first few values, [0] [0] [0], seem to indicate it is about to give the first element in the first array in the main array. At the end it repeats "border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;" several times.